# My code says The array returned by a function changed size between calls

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to draw a graph of f(Pr) IN PYTHON i enred all the needed commands but it still shows the next errors, ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pandas as pd

A1=0.32650
A2=-1.07000
A3=-0.53390
A4=0.01569
A5=-0.05165
A6=0.54750
A7=-0.73610
A8=0.18440
A9=0.10560
A10=0.61340
A11=0.72100
Pr=np.linspace(0.2,15,num=20)
Tr=2
zguess=0.2
x0=0
RO=(0.27*Pr)/(zguess*Tr)
C1=A1+A2/Tr+A3/Tr**3+A4/Tr**4+A5/Tr**5
C2=A6+A7/Tr+A8/Tr**2
C3=A9*(A7/Tr+A8/Tr**2)
C4=A10*(1+A11*RO**2)*(RO**2/Tr**3)*np.exp(-A11*RO**2)
def F(f,RO,C1,C2,C3,C4):
    return f-(1+C1*RO+C2*RO**2-C3*RO**5+C4)
f=np.empty(len(Pr))    
for i in range(len(f)):
    f[i]=fsolve(F,x0,args=(Pr[i],C1,C2,C3,C4))
plt.figure(num=0,dpi=120)
plt.plot(Pr,F)
```

so the shown error is like this one here

```
runfile('C:/Users/Soft/Desktop/dranchuk correlation/dranchuk.py', wdir='C:/Users/Soft/Desktop/dranchuk correlation')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Soft\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\soft\desktop\dranchuk correlation\dranchuk.py", line 37, in <module>
    f[i]=fsolve(F,x0,args=(Pr[i],C1,C2,C3,C4))

  File "C:\Users\Soft\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 160, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)

  File "C:\Users\Soft\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 237, in _root_hybr
    retval = _minpack._hybrd(func, x0, args, 1, xtol, maxfev,

****ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls****
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to solve a non-linear equation. The function `fsolve` is not able to find a solution for all values of `Pr`.
You can see this by plotting the function `F` for different values of `Pr`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pandas as pd

A1=0.32650
A2=-1.07000
A3=-0.53390
A4=0.01569
A5=-0.05165
A6=0.54750
A7=-0.73610
A8=0.18440
A9=0.10560
A10=0.61340
A11=0.72100
Pr=np.linspace(0.2,15,num=20)
Tr=2
zguess=0.2
x0=0
RO=(0.27*Pr)/(zguess*Tr)
C1=A1+A2/Tr+A3/Tr**3+A4/Tr**4+A5/Tr**5
C2=A6+A7/Tr+A8/Tr**2
C3=A9*(A7/Tr+A8/Tr**2)
C4=A10*(1+A11*RO**2)*(RO**2/Tr**3)*np.exp(-A11*RO**2)
def F(f,RO,C1,C2,C3,C4):
    return f-(1+C1*RO+C2*RO**2-C3*RO**5+C4)

for i in range(len(Pr)):
    plt.plot(RO, F(x0, RO, C1, C2, C3, C4))
```

You can see that for some values of `Pr` the function `F` has no solution. To fix this error, you can use `np.nan` to replace the values of `f` that are not found.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pandas as pd

A1=0.32650
A2=-1.07000
A3=-0.53390
A4=0.01569
A5=-0.05165
A6=0.54750
A7=-0.73610
A8=0.18440
A9=0.10560
A10=0.61340
A11=0.72100
Pr=np.linspace(0.2,15,num=20)
Tr=2
zguess=0.2
x0=0
RO=(0.27*Pr)/(zguess*Tr)
C1=A1+A2/Tr+A3/Tr**3+A4/Tr**4+A5/Tr**5
C2=A6+A7/Tr+A8/Tr**2
C3=A9*(A7/Tr+A8/Tr**2)
C4=A10*(1+A11*RO**2)*(RO**2/Tr**3)*np.exp(-A11*RO**2)
def F(f,RO,C1,C2,C3,C4):
    return f-(1+C1*RO+C2*RO**2-C3*RO**5+C4)
f=np.empty(len(Pr))    
for i in range(len(f)):
    try:
        f[i]=fsolve(F,x0,args=(Pr[i],C1,C2,C3,C4))
    except:
        f[i] = np.nan
plt.figure(num=0,dpi=120)
plt.plot(Pr,F)
```